# React + NPM Material UI: Npm install error Unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: node.js, npm, material-ui

After installing materialUI I'm having issues when trying to run an npm install on my application that was created with create-react-app.

I've tried deleting node_modules & package_lock.json multiple times - issue persists.

I can continue to install npm packages using --force however, not ideal. I'd like to understand what the issue is here.

Error:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "video-upload",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.1.6",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.0",
    "@svgr/webpack": "2.4.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.4",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.9",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-named-asset-import": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.0",
    "bfj": "6.1.1",
    "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "chalk": "2.4.1",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "dotenv": "6.0.0",
    "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
    "eslint": "5.6.0",
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^3.0.6",
    "eslint-loader": "2.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.50.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.11.1",
    "file-loader": "2.0.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin-alt": "0.4.14",
    "fs-extra": "7.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest-pnp-resolver": "1.0.1",
    "jest-resolve": "23.6.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.3",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "pnp-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "4.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.3.1",
    "postcss-safe-parser": "4.0.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-polyfill": "^0.2.0",
    "react-dev-utils": "^7.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.4.4",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "resolve": "1.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "7.1.0",
    "style-loader": "0.23.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3",
    "url-loader": "1.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "webpack": "4.19.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.1.14",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "3.6.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "resolver": "jest-pnp-resolver",
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts",
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^react-native$": "react-native-web",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your package 'fe-react-app-video-upload' has a dependency on `react@18.2.0`

It could not match that, given you are installing an **old** version of MUI. As I see it, you are trying to install MUI with the old method.
The updated version of Material-UI for React, is available at the `@mui/xxx` org.

Now, if you really do want v4 of MUI, for some reason, you have to force install. That's because v4 has a dependency on old React, while the first package I mentioned, has a dependency on React 18.2.0; any lower version won't do, only higher versions given the `^` symbol in front.

Comment: Thank you, I found the answer by removing the older installed version of material ui and installing the most recent version here: https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/

Comment: Hey mate, could you mark this as an answer, then? I would like to think it directed you toward the right solution.